# Associate an object with a regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way I can link/associate an object (in this particular case a function) with a regular expression pattern?

Here's the function I'm working on:

```
def get_command(url):
    """
    Return command for downloading a particular url.

    >>> get_command('http://randomsite.com/XYZ')
    ['wget', '--content-disposition', '--continue', '--quiet', 'http://randomsite.com/XYZ']

    >>> get_command('http://examplesite.com/XYZ')
    ['/usr/bin/torify', 'wget', '--content-disposition', '--continue', '--quiet', '--referer=http://referersite.com', 'http://examplesite.com/XYZ']

    >>> get_command('https://mega.nz/%23!xd432Afds')
    ['megadl', '--no-progress', 'https://mega.nz/#!xd432Afds']

    >>> get_command('https://mega.nz/#!s2JHj1fds')
    ['megadl', '--no-progress', 'https://mega.nz/#!s2JHj1fds']

    >>> get_command('http://othersite.com/XYZ')
    ['downloadtool', 'http://othersite.com/XYZ']
    """
    import re

    base = ['wget', '--content-disposition', '--continue', '--quiet']

    # examplesite.com via torified wget and special referer
    if re.match(r'(https?://)?examplesite\.com/.+$', url):
        return ['/usr/bin/torify'] + base + \
            ['--referer=http://referersite.com', url]
    # MEGA via megadl of megatools
    elif re.match(r'https://mega\.nz/.+$', url):
        # fix url if necessary
        return ['megadl', '--no-progress', url.replace('%23', '#', 1)]
    # othersite.com via a dedicated download tool
    elif re.match(r'(https?://)?othersite\.com/.+$', url):
        return ['downloadtool', url]
    # default wget command
    else:
        return base + [url]
```

I think the aforementioned code is pretty straightforward, but it got me thinking whether there's a good way to refactor this. As the if-chain of `re.match(pattern, url)` gets longer, it starts to look more and more necessary.

Perhaps ideally I'd have a dictionary of patterns with their associated functions. Anyways here's what I ended up with:

```
def get_command(url):
    """Return command for downloading a particular url."""
    import re

    base = ['wget', '--content-disposition', '--continue', '--quiet']

    commands = [
        # examplesite.com via torified wget and special referer
        (r'(https?://)?examplesite\.com/.+$',
         lambda u: ['/usr/bin/torify'] + base +
         ['--referer=http://referersite.com', u]),
        # MEGA via megadl of megatools (fix url if necessary)
        (r'https://mega\.nz/.+$',
         lambda u: ['megadl', '--no-progress', u.replace('%23', '#', 1)]),
        # othersite.com via a dedicated download tool
        (r'(https?://)?othersite\.com/.+$',
         lambda u: ['downloadtool', u])
    ]

    return next(
        (f for p, f in commands if re.match(p, url)), lambda u: base + [u]
    )(url)
```

Doesn't seem like much of an improvement, potentially the opposite. Anyone have a good way to refactor this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see that you do `lambda u: data + [u]` on all of the commands.
The exception to this is when you do `u.replace('%23', '#', 1)`,
this can be replaced by [`urllib.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) and will allow for more urls.

You should put `base`, `commands` and `re` into global scope.
If you also change the commands so that you don't use lambda's and just have the lists then you can get:

```
try:
    #Python2
    from urllib import unquote
except ImportError:
    #Python3
    from urllib.parse import unquote
import re

BASE = ['wget', '--content-disposition', '--continue', '--quiet']
COMMANDS = [
    (
        r'(https?://)?examplesite\.com/.+$',
        ['/usr/bin/torify'] + BASE + ['--referer=http://referersite.com']
    ),
    (
        r'https://mega\.nz/.+$',
        ['megadl', '--no-progress']
    ),
    (
        r'(https?://)?othersite\.com/.+$',
        ['downloadtool']
    )
]

def get_command(url):
    """Return command for downloading a particular url."""
    url = unquote(url)
    commands = next((f for p, f in COMMANDS if re.match(p, url)), BASE)
    return commands + [url]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The `unquote` really did the trick!